# Background image with gradient overlay React

Tags: css, reactjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to set a background image for a div and adding a color overlay to it. With plain CSS this would look something like this:

```
.backgroundImage {
 background-image:
 linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(245, 246, 252, 0.52), rgba(117, 19, 93, 0.73)),
 url('../img/backgroundimage.jpg');
 width: auto;
 height: 40vh;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

This CSS approach doesn't work for me though, as the component I am building will be filled dynamically (different pictures, text content etc.).

I've tried importing an image and doing the same as in the css stated above. Somehow I can set the background image but can't get the gradient overlay to work inside of my style object.

So my next approach was to wrap my div in another div and just set the gradient there. That also doesn't seem to work...

I hope someone smarter than me has an answer to this...

Cheers!

```
const wrapperPictureBox {
 background: "linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(245, 246, 252, 0.52), rgba(117, 19, 93, 0.73))"
}

const pictureBox = {
 background: ` url(${backgroundimage})`,
 height: "40vh",
 backgroundSize: "cover",
};

 <div style={wrapperPictureBox}>
  <div style={pictureBox}>text</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go the CSS variable way. This [codepen](https://codepen.io/kmurphs/pen/bGwzEXy) demonstrates.

Basically, in the `React` file:

```
<div style={{"--img": "url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1610907083431-d36d8947c8e2')"}}>text</div>
```

And, in CSS:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(245, 246, 252, 0.52), rgba(117, 19, 93, 0.73)), var(--img);
```

If the gradient must also be dynamic, a similar approach should work still.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's working now! Just out of curiosity, how would I have ever come to that solution myself? I probably could have read the whole documentation and never come up with the right solution...

Comment: I'm afraid there is no shortcut to it. You get stuck, find a solution, and months down the line, you can recognize this issue in someone else's code. You can then impart a little bit of this hard-earned experience. Keep going.

Comment: Thank you. this is so helpful, it has worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer works well.

I am just adding another option you would like to use.

You can have the img url as **PROPS** just to make your code more Dynamic and robust.

Here is my use case:

```
function SndHeader({ bgImage }) {
    return (
      <div className="sndHeader" style={{ "--img": `url(${bgImage}), 
      linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5)` }}>
      <h1>Your Title</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

my CSS looks very minimal and helps you centre everything within the Div

```
.sndHeader {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 57px 57px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center top;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(245, 246, 252, 
    0.52), rgba(117, 19, 93, 0.73)),
    var(--img);
    background-size: cover;
}
```